# Shutdown command : The process can't access the file, because it is being used by another process

Tags: batch-file, cmd, shutdown

I'm trying to write a batch file that, when run, will shutdown my computer if there's no internet available. I'm using windows 10. Content of the batch file

```
@echo off

set "host=192.168.1.1"

ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (

    echo Success.

) else (

    shutdown -s -t 60 2> D:/Projects/log.txt

)
```

However when the "shutdown -s -t 60" command runs (or any shutdown variation), it prints an error (redirected to errror file) that specifies 
"The process can't access the file, because it is being used by another process.". It works just fine when I run it manually from the cmd.

Comment: To start off, not related to your issue. This would be a better findstr query `ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr "TTL"`. But then for the `if` statement, I would do this rather. `if "%errorlevel%" == "0" echo success || shutdown -s -t 60 2> "D:\Projects\log.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if your internet connection is working test something on the internet not your router.  Backward slash in windows in D:\Projects\log.txt.  The error message: "The process can't access the file, because it is being used by another process." is occurring because you are trying to do something with D:\Projects\log.txt.  The batch must finish before you try to do something with log.txt.  D:\Projects must exist.

```
    @echo off
    set host=8.8.8.8
    ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr "TTL"
    if %errorlevel% == 0 (
        echo Success.
    ) else (
        md D:\Projects\
        shutdown -s -t 60 > D:\Projects\log.txt
    )
    exit /b
```